# Grocery crud to show display name instead of ID

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, grocery-crud

In my application I have two tables

**orders:**

*order_id*

*order_number*

**products:**

*product_id*

*product name*

*order_id(foreign key)*

and in my phpmyadmin I chose **order_id to display as order_number** but when I render the view associated with products it displays **order_id**. is there any way that it can *order_number instead of order_id*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your question, enough adding the following line in the **products** controller, before rendering of course.

```
$crud->set_relation('order_id','orders','order_number');
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, by configuring the **Relation view** you can select which column is displayed here.

From the `products` table, go to the Structure tab, then the Relation view sub-tab:

[image: Relation view tab]

Set up the relation as so:

[image: Relation creation]

Alternatively, use the Designer tab from the database level to do the same:

[image: Creating relations with Designer]

(hint: I think Designer is generally easier).

Next, from the `orders` table go to the Relations view and find "Choose column to display" about halfway down the page; pick `order_number` there so phpMyAdmin knows which column you wish to display.

[image: Choose column to display dialog]

One last step -- back on the `products` table, in the Browse view, expand the Options area part way down the page. Toggle the radio button to **Display column for relations** and press Go.

[image: Options dialog]

Now when you Browse the `products` table, the `order_number` is displayed instead of the `order_id`.

[image: orders table]
[image: products table]

Comment: thanks but I have tried that option in database it is showing as what you have demonstrated but when extracting data to display from grocery crud its still showing the id however names are displaying in database as selected as column to display.

Comment: So you've done all the steps listed except in the last picture where my `order_id` is showing 100 yours shows 1 (or the equivalent, of course)? What storage engine are the tables? Which phpMyAdmin version? In the Browse view, is `order_id` a blue link or black text?

Comment: yes its all so. its displaying name instead of id when i hover over it , it then displays id but when I apply the select query in phpmyadmin and to display names instead of ids but at that time it only displays ids in select query as well.I think its not do do with grocery crud but I am curious to ask why its not displaying the display name in select query but ids even the display name is visible and is there any possibility that I may be able to retrieve display names instead of ids?